# how can i iterate with loop in sampler2D

Tags: data-structures, glsl, webgl

I have some data encoded in a floating point texture 2k by 2k. The data are longitude, latitude, time, and date as R,G,B,A. Those are all normalized but for now that is not a problem. I can de-normalize them later if i want to.

What i need now is to iterate through the whole texture and find what longitude, latitude should be in that fragment coordinate. I assume that the whole atlas has normalized coordinates and it maps the whole openGL context. Besides coordinates i will filter data with time and date but that is an if condition that is easy to be done. Because pixel coordinates that i have will not map exactly that coordinate i will use a small delta value to fix that issue for now and i will sue that delta value to precompute other points that are close to that co.

Now i have some driver crashes on iGPU (it should be out of memory or something similar) even if i want to add something in 2 for nested loops or even if I use a discard.

The code i now is this
NOTE f_time is the filter for the time and for now i have a slider so that i will have some interaction with the values.

precision mediump float;
    precision mediump int;

```
const int maxTextureSize = 2048;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

uniform float f_time; 
uniform ivec2 textureDimensions;

void main(void) {
    float delta = 0.001;// now bigger delta just to make it work then we tune it

    // compute 1 pixel in texture coordinates.
    vec2 onePixel = vec2(1.0, 1.0) / float(textureDimensions.x);
    vec2 position = ( gl_FragCoord.xy /  float(textureDimensions.x) );

    vec4 color =  texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
    vec4 outColor = vec4(0.0);

    float dist_x = distance( color.r, gl_FragCoord.x);
    float dist_y = distance( color.g, gl_FragCoord.y);
    //float dist_x = distance( color.g, gl_PointCoord.s);
    //float dist_y = distance( color.b, gl_PointCoord.t);
    for(int i = 0; i < maxTextureSize; i++){
        if(i < textureDimensions.x ){
            break;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j <  maxTextureSize ; j++){
                if(j < textureDimensions.y ){
                    break;
                }
             // Where i am stuck now how to get the texture coordinate and test it with fragment shader
                // the precomputation
            vec4 pixel= texture2D(u_texture,vec2(i,j));
            if(pixel.r > f_time){
                    outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                    // for now just break, no delta calculation to sum this point with others so that 
                    // we will have an approximation of other points into that pixel
                        break;
                }
            }
    }

    // this works   
    if(color.t > f_time){
        //gl_FragColor = color;//;vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }

    gl_FragColor = outColor;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is simply not feasible.

You are trying to access a texture up to *four million times*, all within a single fragment shader invocation.

The way modern GPUs usually detect infinite loop conditions is by seeing how long your shader runs, and then killing it if it has run for "too long", the length of which is usually sufficiently generous. Your code, which does up to 4 million texture accesses, will almost certainly trigger this condition.

Which typically leads to a GPU reset.

Generally speaking, the way you would find the position in a texture which is associated with some fragment is to do so *directly*. That is, create a 1:1 correspondence between screen fragment locations (`gl_FragCoord`) and texels in the texture. That way, your texture does not need to contain X/Y coordinates, and each fragment shader can access the data meant for that specific invocation.

What you're trying to do seems to be to pass a large table (four million elements) to the GPU, and then have the GPU process it. The ordering of values is (generally) irrelevant; any value could potentially modify any pixel. Some pixels don't have values applied to them, while others may have multiple values applied.

This is *serial* programmer thinking, not parallel thinking. The way you'd code that on the CPU is to walk each element in the table, look at where it goes, and build the results for each pixel.

In a parallel algorithm, you don't work that way. Each invocation needs to be able to instantly find the data in the table that applies to it. You should *never* be doing some kind of search through a table for your data. Especially not a *linear* search.

You need to think of this from the perspective of your fragment shader.

In your data table, for each position on the screen, there is a list of data values that apply to that screen position. Correct? What you need to do is make that list *directly available* to each fragment shader invocation. And since each fragment's list is not constant in size, you will need to use a linked list rather than a fixed-size array.

To do this, you build a texture the size of your render target. Each texel in the texture specifies the location in the data table of the *first* element that this fragment needs to process. This provides every fragment shader invocation with the location of its first element. Since some fragment shaders may have no data applied to them, you need to set aside some special texture coordinate value to represent "none".

The data in the data table consists of your time and date, but rather than "longitude/latitude", it has the texture coordinate of the *next* texel in the texture that applies for that fragment shader. This is how you make a linked list in shaders. Each location in the data table specifies the next location to be processed.

If that location was the last data to be processed, then the location will be the "none" value from before.

You should also be using a [buffer texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture) or an [SSBO](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) to hold your data table, rather than a 2D texture. It would make things much easier.

Comment: I am developing this in Web GL and as I see there are no buffer texture or SSBO for WebGL. This is a requirement from the professor that asked me to do this prototype and this is the way he asked me to do. 
What you are saying is completely the opposite way of doing this. Also when I leave the loops un-commented the shader works fine but I don’t do any operations in then and I leave the fragColor at the end as you would do with any normal shader. 
What if i use a smaller texture for how. like 256x256 just to have it working as a prototype.

Comment: 256x256 is 65536. That's the number of texture accesses you would have to do. I can't say for certain if it's too many in general, but at the very least, you'd be pushing the boundaries of what is permissible. I'd say that the best you could do for your professor is try a few sizes and show him the largest size that actually works.

Comment: I have a meeting with him in about 1 hour and I will let him know. Thank you .